# Problems getting started with phonegap, a little bit confused

Tags: cordova, mobile

I want to make a cross platform mobile app with phonegap and have done some research. I understand that phonegap is build on cordova, but I am a little confused as to how to start with it. One tutorial says you don't need any SDK's and just can build it with the adobe cloud build, and the other says you need to download 3 or 4 SDK's.

My app needs to be cross platform but the priority lays with windows phone 8 and windows 8, does this mean I need to start in VS with the cordova SDK, build my app in HTML, JS and CSS and then use the cloud build, or would I only have a windows app then?

Any information or guidelines would help and be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can either use adobe cloud build or install the SDK.If you prefer WP8/Win8 then you can use HTML 5 and WinJS to get a native universal  app as well.

Comment: But can I use the build still after I made the app with VS and the SDK ?

Comment: I guess you will be able to.To use the build, there needs to be a particular project structure, index.html should be at the root, if your project structure is fine you should be able to compile in adobe cloud

Comment: yeah you could check this for your project structure http://gihankarunarathne.github.io/DocBook-xsl-mobile/content/ch02s04.html and https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki